# Making PUT create request idempotent in REST API

Tags: rest, http, put, idempotent

My goal is to make idempotent /create REST API which is implemented as PUT verb.

[Idempotent RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2)   states:

> Idempotent methods are distinguished because the request can be
> repeated automatically if a communication failure occurs before the
> client is able to read the server's response.  For example, if a
> client sends a PUT request and the underlying connection is closed
> before any response is received, then the client can establish a new
> connection and retry the idempotent request.  It knows that repeating
> the request will have the same intended effect, even if the original
> request succeeded, though the response might differ.

[PUT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) states:

> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the
> PUT successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the
> user agent by sending a 201 (Created) response.  If the target
> resource does have a current representation and that representation
> is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed
> representation, then the origin server MUST send either a 200 (OK) or
> a 204 (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the
> request.

Assuming that /create stores the created resource in DB, should it return 201 on first creation and 200 on retried /create?
Should retried /create store the same resource in DB all over again to conform with PUT RFC?

Comment: Use POST for save, and PUT to update.

Comment: my goal is to make PUT /create idempotent. It means that it can be retried

Comment: How will you know whether to create a resouce or update it?

Comment: i will check if one exists with the same id

Comment: And you will you get the ID? Just curious, because `PUT /` and `PUT /:id` are 2 different resources

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27728163/put-post-being-idempotent-rest explains it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161398/discussion-between-user1264304-and-ayush-gupta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this question is a bit confused.  Let's see if we can untangle it.

```
PUT /create

abcde
```

Says roughly: replace the state of `/create` with representation `abcde`.  In other words, the semantics of the message are something along the lines of

```
store(key => "/create", value => "abcde")
```

Notice that processing this message twice produces the same effect as processing the message once.

```
store(key => "/create", value => "abcde")
store(key => "/create", value => "abcde")
```

Notice that we're being very specific about the key that we are using here; PUT relates to the state of the *target resource*; `PUT /create` is a message requesting that we modify `/create`, not a request that we create some *other* resource.

> Assuming that /create stores the created resource in DB, should it return 201 on first creation and 200 on retried /create?

Yes.

> Should retried /create store the same resource in DB all over again to conform with PUT RFC?

If the *resource* already has the requested *representation*, you don't need to store it again.

Comment: thanks a lot. _If the resource already has the requested representation, you don't need to store it again._ If i get it right, the only way to achieve it is to retrieve the resource from DB and compare it with the resource representation in the body.